# Testing PdfDocument with RobolectricTestRunner/AndroidJUnit4: document is closed

Tags: android, testing, junit, robolectric, pdfdocument

I am trying to test with Robolectric or AndroidJUnit4 some pdf generation in my android application (using `android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument`).

```
@Test
fun testPdfDocument() {
    val doc = PdfDocument()
    val builder = PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(20, 10, 1)
    val pdf = builder.create()
    assertEquals(0, doc.pages.size)
    val page = doc.startPage(pdf) // java.lang.IllegalStateException: document is closed!
    doc.finishPage(page)
    assertEquals(1, doc.pages.size)
}
```

The code above crashes, with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: document is closed!`. Any idea why?

Comment: N.B.: I abstracted my app code to only have the critical part that fails. See more PdfDocument tests here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/pdf/src/android/graphics/pdf/cts/PdfDocumentTest.java

Comment: I also tried using `PrintedPdfDocument` instead but I had the same issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please, notify if you will have found any decision. Thank you!

Comment: I receive the following error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument.nativeCreateDocument()J during PdfDocument. Do.you have the same problem?

Comment: Mine is : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: document is closed!`

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Any updates?